# Return focus out of embedded broswer

Tags: javascript, focus

I am working in a desktop application that has an embedded browser. There is a process that loads a page in this embedded browser and sets the focus on it.

This is not wanted and disturbs. An interesting detail is that if I create an alert after the page gets loaded, when I click to close it, the focurs return to the "host" desktop application, which is exactly what I want.

Is there a way in javascript to tell "turn back the focus to wherever it was"?

Thanks in advance.